# Python Pydf throwing exception 'module' object has no attribute 'poll'

Tags: python

I've been struggling with this exception for a while. 
Simply I'm trying to save a string into a pdf using pydf library. This is quite straight forward as in [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-pdf). If I run the below script in a standalone python script it works perfectly fine

```
import pydf
alarm_report = "test"
file_name = "test.pdf"
pdf = pydf.generate_pdf(alarm_report)
   with open(str(file_name), 'w') as f:
   f.write(pdf)
```

However, when I try to integrate it into the software I'm developing I get the following exception:

```
File "/home/cayman/multiviewer/src/alarm_log/alarm_db_utils.py", line 116, in db_export_to_pdf
    pdf = pydf.generate_pdf(str(alarm_report))   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydf/wkhtmltopdf.py", line 121, in generate_pdf
    return gen_pdf(html_file.name, cmd_args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydf/wkhtmltopdf.py", line 105, in gen_pdf
    _, stderr, returncode = execute_wk(*cmd_args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydf/wkhtmltopdf.py", line 23, in execute_wk
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 799, in communicate
    return self._communicate(input)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1409, in _communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate_with_poll(input)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1439, in
_communicate_with_poll
    poller = select.poll()
```

Any idea what's causing this problem ?

Comment: Post stack traces with code formatting, not quote formatting. Quote formatting loses information and is unreadable.

Comment: Make sure you didn't name any of your files or packages the same as a built-in module. For example, `select.py`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I made sure that I didn't use any reserved names